# Stumped. LocalStorage.key string won't match stringified number

Tags: javascript, html

I have a localStorage file made up of numeric keys. To write a new key, value pair to the file, I want to make sure the key does not already exist.  If it does exist, I add one to the key and test again if it's present. It's a small set, so I thought this could be handled with a straightforward iteration of all keys and a check for match, e.g.:

```
var CheckItAintThere = function() {
    for ( var i = 0, len = window.localStorage.length; i < len; ++i )
    {
        var Foundit = false;
        console.log('checking for duplicate to see if '+window.localStorage.key(i)+' is equal to '+SaveNumber);

        if (window.localStorage.getItem( window.localStorage.key(i) ) == SaveNumber.toString())
        {
             console.log('FOUNDIT TRUE');
             Foundit = true;
        }
    }

    while (Foundit == true) {
        SaveNumber = SaveNumber + 1;
        if (localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ) !== SaveNumber.toString()) 
        { 
            console.log('SaveNumber = '+SaveNumber+' LocalStoragekey =  '+localStorage.key(i));
            Foundit = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But Foundit never tests true, even when the console.log reports:

```
> checking for duplicate to see if 0 is equal to 3 
> checking for duplicate to see if 1 is equal to 3 
> checking for duplicate to see if 3 is equal to 3
```

I tried adding .toString() to the key, but as I understand it keys are stored as strings anyway, and this had no impact.

I have a feeling I'm going to have a palmprint on my forehead, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use `window.localStorage.key(i)` to log the check start, but use the `item` to compare with the `SaveNumber`, which is the one you're checking for duplicates, `key` or `item`?

Comment: localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i )) generates the key rather than the value, and console.log looks right on that point.

Comment: Your browser seems to get a weird result from what you've said, created a __[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aevk9s3/)__, what I get from `localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key(i))` is its value.

Comment: I just realised my while (Foundit == true) loop won't function as it doesn't iterate across the keys... but I'll leave that in place for now as the more fundamental question is why Foundit never fires as true.

Comment: Your code seems easy enough to create a snippet that can reproduce the error result, why not make one and we can find the problem quicker?

Comment: Here's the core of the problem [as a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/brianfit/cfw6tha8/)

Comment: Here's the altered version of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfw6tha8/1/), seems work after change what I've said.

Comment: Facepalm. That was it. Thanks! I'm still mystified why it works differently. I could understand if the retrieved value were an object rather than a string, but it didn't work even when I converted it using .toString()

Comment: Anything you set to `localStorage` will become `string`, so if you try to store `Object`, localStorage will call `.toString` on that `Object`, and your value may become something like `[object Object]` or else, but not you expected, when try to set value to `localString`, check if it can be represent in string form, if not, try use `JSON.stringify` or any function that is able to create a string form object for you. You can see https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/#storage-0.